# mutation not seen by subcriber vue

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, vite

Am creating a application in vue 3 with vite and vuex and i'm experience some problems with store.subscriber event.

I'm trying to store the token in a mutation which the subsribe method doesn't see. This only happens when i reload the page, if i fire the event from a login form everyting seems fine.

Main.js

```
store.dispatch('auth/attempt', localStorage.getItem('token')).then(() => {
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = mitt();
app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
app.use(router)
    .use(store)
    .use(VueToast)
    .use(i18n)
    .mount('#app')
```

});

Auth.js

```
state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    user: {}
},

getters: {
    authenticated(state) {
        return state.token && state.user;
    },

    user(state) {
        return state.user;
    }
},

mutations: {
    SET_TOKEN (state, token) {
        state.token = token;
    },
    SET_USER (state, user) {
        state.user = user;
    },
    ADD_USER_DATA: (state, data) => {
        Object.keys(data).forEach( key => {
            Vue.set(state.user, key, data[key])
        })
    }
},

actions: {
    async signIn({ dispatch }, credentials) {
        let response = await api.post('auth/login', credentials);
        return dispatch('attempt', response.token)
    },

    async register({ dispatch }, form) {
        let response = await api.post('register', form);
        return dispatch('attempt', response.data.token)
    },

    async attempt ({ commit, state, dispatch } , token) {

        if(token) {
            commit('SET_TOKEN', token)
        }

        if(!state.token) {
            return
        }

        try {
            let response = await api.get('user');

            response.currencies.forEach((item) => {
                item.name = Object.keys(environment.currencies).filter(k=>environment.currencies[k] === item.type).toString()
            })

            //dispatch('votes/total', null, {root:true})
            commit('SET_USER', response.data)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    },

    signOut({ commit }) {
        return api.post('logout').then(() => {
            commit('SET_TOKEN', null)
            commit('SET_USER', null)
        })
    }
}
```

}

[As you can see for my notifications the subscribe see the event bus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxElP.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the fix. Just created plugin in vuex instead of import subscriber in main.js and that solve the issue.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below and accept it so that it could help others with the same problem.